# How do I get @apply to work in TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I can't seem to get TailwindCSS @apply to work. Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to recognise my code.

[image]

```
.btn {
  @apply mb-2 bg-purple-600 text-gray-100 font-bold p-3 rounded;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No tailwind class names you defined in the apply command '.' you don't need to put it.

As a solution, write all tailwind elements in one line.

```
.btn {
  @apply mb-2 bg-purple-600 text-gray-100 font-bold p-3 rounded;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it all in one line:

```css
.btn {
  @apply mb-2 bg-purple-600 text-gray-100 font-bold p-3 rounded;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is not the case, see the official post: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/utility-first